# Website does not display properly

Tags: html, css

Hello, at the moment I am facing 2 problems with my website:

1. The fact that when I scroll down the text pops over the other topbar

   2. The fact that I have 3 radio buttons and one of them is constantly selected, and I want for the user to able to select one of them at a time

This is the website http://www.onetechsearch.com/

```
            <style type="text/css">
            #picture-side {
              display: block; 
            float:left;
              z-index: 10; 
              top: 10px; 
              left: 10px; 
            }
            input[type="radio"]:checked+label{ border-bottom: 5px solid lime; } 

            #picture-side1 {
              display: block; 
            float:left;
              z-index: 10; 
              top: 10px; 
              left: 10px; 
            }

            .site-wrap {
                display: none;
            }

            #picture-side2 {
              display: block; 
            float:left;
              z-index: 10; 
              top: 10px; 
              left: 10px; 
            }

            #picture2 {
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            #video {
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            #picture {
                visibility: hidden;
            }




</style>
<script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var cat= ["Australia", "Bangladesh", "Denmark", "Hong Kong", "Indonesia", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "South Africa", "C"];
                $("#cat").select2({
                  data: cat
                });
            });
        </script>


    <div id="topbar">
        <div class="width-container">
            <h1><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
            <div id="search">
                <form action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/recipes" method="GET" id="searchF">
                <?php
                    $searched_term = get_query_var('recipe_search');

                    if (empty($searched_term)) {
                        $searched_term = isset($_GET["search"]) ? $_GET["search"] : "";
                    }
                ?>
                <input id="sfield" type="text" name="search" placeholder="keywords" <?php if (!empty($searched_term)) {echo 'value="'.$searched_term.'"';} ?>>
                <input type="submit" value="Search">

            <div id="picture-side">

                <input type="radio" name="images" value="1" id="picture" 
                <?php if(isset($_GET["images"]) && $_GET["images"]=='1'){ echo 'Checked';} ?>><label for="picture">With Pictures</label>
            </div>

            <div id="picture-side1">

                <input type="radio" name="images" value="0" id="picture2" 
                <?php if(isset($_GET["images"]) && $_GET["images"]=='0'){ echo 'checked';} ?>><label for="picture2">Without Pictures</label>
            </div>  

            <div id="picture-side2">

                <input type="radio" name="video" value="0" id="video" 
                <?php if(isset($_GET["video"]) && $_GET["video"]=='0'){ echo 'checked';} ?>><label for="video">With video</label> 
            </div>      


                    <div id="time-side">
                        <!--<small>Published time</small>-->
                        <input type="text" id="from-side" name="from" placeholder="Start date"
                    </div>


                    <select id="cat" name="cat">
                        <option value="all" selected>All categories</option>
                        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                        <option value="C">Hawaji</option>

                    </select>   
            </div>  
</div>  
            </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add a lower z-index to the #middle_container styles.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your Radio buttons must have the same name value to work as a group
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

Comment: Thank you, I meant that when I scroll down on the page (I added the website as well) the title of the post goes over the topbar

Answer (score 0):

Your topbar's z-index is set to 999, "smtitle" also has the same z-index the only thing you need to do is to set "smtitle" z-index to 998 or lower if possible.

Answer (score -1):

The link you provided has the 'images' GET variable set and it's set to empty which in php means 0. This makes your check `$_GET["images"]=='0'` to validate as `TRUE`.

Comment: I fixed the radio buttons, now my only problem is the fact that the title goes over the topbar